# Large file deleting multiple lines in Perl

Tags: perl, parsing, file-io, while-loop

I have a large file I want to remove multiple lines from using Perl, so slurping is not an option.

Its a spice file is something like this:

```
X1 param param param
+param param param
+param param param
X2 param param param
+param param param
+param param param
+param param param
X3 param param param
+**target_param** param param param
+param param param
+param param param
X4 param **target_param** param param
+param param param
+param param param
```

The target could be anywhere, and any instance i.e. any lines starting with X(N) to but not including X(N+1) need to omitted from output file.

Sample Output:

```
X1 param param param
+param param param
+param param param
X2 param param param
+param param param
+param param param
+param param param
```

Comment: Please add a sample of the expected output for a given value of `n`

Answer (score 1):

Could this be a solution? It does not include the second occurrence of the `target_parameter`.

**Update:** Solution now just looks for the `target_parameter` in a 'block', not in consecutive blocks (as I first understood the problem).

```
#!/usr/bin/perl
use strict;
use warnings;

{
    local $/ = 'X';
    <DATA>; # discard first block (empty)
    while (<DATA>) {
        chomp;
        print "X$_" unless /target_param/;
    }   
}
__DATA__
X1 param param param
+param param param
+param param param
X2 param param param
+param param param
+param param param
+param param param
X3 param param param
+**target_param** param param param
+param param param
+param param param
X4 param **target_param** param param
+param param param
+param param param
X5 param param
+param param param
X6 param param param
+param param param **target_param**
+param param param
+param param param
X7 param **target_param** param param
+param param param
+param param param
X8 param param param
+param param param
+param param param
```

The output from this data is:

```
C:\Old_Data\perlp>perl try.pl
X1 param param param
+param param param
+param param param
X2 param param param
+param param param
+param param param
+param param param
X5 param param
+param param param
X8 param param param
+param param param
+param param param
```

Comment: That is an elegant piece of code, but that will only omit instance when "target" is in the same line as X4, X7 etc. This is how far I got initially. It should NOT print the "X3" line, so without using push I couldn't find a way to "look ahead" several lines in Perl without incrementing $_.

Comment: The code reads in 'blocks' delimited by 'X' rather than by newlines. So, it is reading 1 record at a time. If `target_parameter` is anywhere in the block, (not just in the first line of the block), the program should detect it correctly.

Comment: One problem may be if there is more than 1 instance of `target_parameter` within a block. If that is possible, then then 3 dot range operator, ..., needs to be used rather than the 2 dot, .., operator.

Comment: @user2665672 I've updated the solution and I believe this is what you're looking for.